# Where is the review button/link?

Tags: support, review

About a week ago I could click "review" near the search bar to review posts from new users. Now, that button/link is gone. What happen? Did I lose those privileges? If so, how can I earn them back?

Comment: Are you definitely logged in? New and anonymous users don't see it, so that seems the most likely cause of it disappearing.

Comment: @DanHulme, look at my reputation points, I have been here a while. Yes, I am logged in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rep required to view the First Posts review queue [was bumped from 125 rep to 500 rep on July 26th](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange). You had enough rep to view it under the old rules but do not any longer. The original suggestion, along with some of the reasons why the SE team chose to move this to 500 rep, can be found in [this answer on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186538/150283).